Nuxt 3.11 stuck at Starting Nuxt
I cant run nuxt project, when I run "npm run dev", there's error:
RollupError: virtual:#internal/nitro/virtual/server-handlers (1:45): Expected ',', got 's' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
Error description
And I keep getting stuck at Starting Nuxt page
enter image description here
I trying to run nuxt project, there's no problem with the installation, when I want to run it, i keep getting stuck at starting nuxt page with error rollup

Looking at similar errors online, looks like you might have either some package being the culprit or some encoding issue somewhere.

This may be a nuxt bug. You can open an issue on GitHub

Because there is a quotation mark in your path.

You need to move your project folder to other paths without quotation marks.

Not sure OP can change that one. But maybe espace it if the bundler missed that part.
